# numpy: boolean indexing and memory usage

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, large-data

Consider the following `numpy` code:

```
A[start:end] = B[mask]
```

Here:

- `A` and `B` are 2D arrays with the same number of columns;
- `start` and `end` are scalars;
- `mask` is a 1D boolean array;
- `(end - start) == sum(mask)`.

In principle, the above operation can be carried out using `O(1)` temporary storage, by copying elements of `B` directly into `A`.

Is this what actually happens in practice, or does `numpy` construct a temporary array for `B[mask]`? If the latter, is there a way to avoid this by rewriting the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using boolean arrays as a index is fancy indexing, so numpy needs to make a copy. 
You could write a cython extension to deal with it, if you getting memory problems.

Comment: +1 for bringing in Cython. It is this kinds of loops that it excels at.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
A[start:end] = B[mask]
```

will -- according to the Python language definition -- first evaluate the right hand side, yielding a new array containing the selected rows of `B` and occupying additional memory.  The most efficient pure-Python way I'm aware of to avoid this is to use an explicit loop:

```
from itertools import izip, compress
for i, b in izip(range(start, end), compress(B, mask)):
    A[i] = b
```

Of course this will be much less time-efficient than your original code, but it only uses O(1) additional memory.  Also note that `itertools.compress()` is available in Python 2.7 or 3.1 or above.

Comment: Surely, "yielding a new array containing the selected rows of B and occupying additional memory" is a non sequitur? It's up to `B.__getitem__()` to choose what it wants to return. For example, if `mask` were a `slice`, a proxy (view) would be returned, and no copy would take place.

Comment: @aix: According to the OP, `mask` is a one-dimensional Boolean array.  Did I miss anything?

Comment: @aix:  Oh, I see.  The part with the language deifnition is a bit ambiguous.  It was only meant to refer to the part "first evaluate the right hand side".

Comment: Yes, I think we understand each other.